# Excel VBA Can't get selected value from combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I've been reading numerous posts here in the forum regarding my problem but I'm afraid I'm still doing something awfully wrong.

Overtaken today by the button rage, I admit to some confusion.
I have been trying to put a simple userform combobox (frmWorkers) which includes a combobox (cbWorkers) and linked to a defined rowSource (Workers), the click of which will simply get me the value of that worker's name. (Thank you Ann!)
The combobox opens just fine but refuses to click and there I'm stopped.

I'm now receiving a 'compile error, for each control variable must be variant or object' at **for each WorkerName...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim wsControl As Worksheet
  Dim Workers As Range
  Dim WorkerName As String

  Set Workers = Range("Workers")

  **For Each WorkerName In Range("Workers")
    If WorkerName = Not Nothing Then
        Me.cbWorkers.AddItem WorkerName
    End If
  End sub
```

I've also been trying to get it alternatively from ThisWorkbook, but I'm getting a 'run-time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set', right after **WorkerName.

```
Sub UsingTheScriptingRunTimeLibrary()

  Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Dim fileMakoret As Scripting.File, filePayroll As Scripting.File
  Dim WorkerName As String, folderPath As String, NewFolderPath As String
  Dim wsControl As Worksheet
  Dim newWbMaskoret As Workbook, wbPayroll As Workbook, wbControl As Workbook
  Dim cbWorkers As ComboBox

  Set wbControl = ActiveWorkbook
  Set wsControl = wbControl.Sheets("Control")
  **WorkerName = cbWorkers.Value

  WorkerName = Worksheets("wsControl").OLEObjects("cbWorkers").Object.Value
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have added a new section to my answer to address your new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the object `frmWorkerName` have a `Value` property?  What type of object is it?

I think the problem with your second code snippet is that you define `cbWorkers`, but you never assign a value to it.  It therefore has a value of `Nothing` ("null" in other languages.)

When you then try to access the value of `cbWorkers`, you get an error, since there is no object there to access a property for.

ETA:   About your second problem:  here's the code:

```
Dim Workers As Range
Dim WorkerName As String

Set Workers = Range("Workers")

For Each WorkerName In Range("Workers")
```

You're getting the error because, to do a `For Each` loop, the type of the variable `WorkerName` needs to be compatible with the type of the collection `Range("Workers")` that you're iterating through.

The error message tells you:  you need to make `WorkerName` an `Object` or a `Variant` if you're going to use it in a `For Each` loop with that collection.

I doubt, by the way, that the elements in an Excel `Range` object are simple strings.  They are probably `Cell` objects, or objects of a type with a similar name.  You will need to cast `WorkerName` to type `Cell` (or whatever) within the loop, and then access its `Text` or `Value` property.

Comment: Hello Ann, the object 'frmWorkerName' is a combobox which I've placed in a 'cbWorkers' UserForm. Any suggestion on how to get those values? (By the way, how do you make those lovely grey rectangles?)

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got those two switched?  In your second code sample, you define `cbWorkers` as a `ComboBox`.

Comment: And, you get the grey boxes by surrounding a keyword with  ` on either side.

Comment: Thank you once again. I've managed to make it work somehow. I honestly can't say how, I'm really coding in the dark. I think now that the fault had really been with me misnaming elements. The code that seems to work for me at the end is the following (I hope that the formatting comes out alright):
`Private Sub cbWorkers_Click()
    Dim WorkerName As String
    WorkerName = cbWorkers.Value
End Sub`